# iTunes Connect app preview not saved and erased by other size

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-preview

I'm trying to upload "app previews" for each size of devices on the ITC (iTunes Connect) and I'm going to freaking out. I really need your help guys.

As Apple asks, I use Safari 9.1.2 under El Capitan to upload my videos on ITC (in 2016 with HTML5/JS that make no sense to force people using Safari for uploading a video... anyway).

Of course before that step I read [Apple's specifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10) and I exported all my videos by respecting their specifications (size, fps, codec, etc.).

One month ago, Apple decided to simplify the "preview and capture" section of ITC because of the increasing number of device and screen size (become difficult to manage). Good idea by the way (in theory).

So I recorded one video preview of my app for each device and started to upload them in each size category. I can upload a preview in his own category without problem until I upload the next one for others devices. Each new uploads for others device erased the last one... I can have only one preview online.

What happens in details:

1)

- I upload my preview for iPhone 5.5 inch
- Upload DONE
- I click SAVE
- Save DONE (I can see the app preview online on iTCo)
- I refresh the page to be sure -> the preview is still here

2)

- I upload the next preview for the 4.7 inch iPhone
- Upload DONE
- Now I can see 2 thumbnails for my 2 preview in each section
- I click SAVE
- The first preview disappears...
- I refresh the page, the first preview is not here... Lost in the Apple's meanders...

I repeated the operations several times, in different way/order, same problem all time.

**---------- UPDATE - 9 september ----------**

I have contacted Apple about this problem and they have answered pretty quickly (less than 24H). You can see below their answer. But this didn't solved my problem...

> *Another developer had a similar issue. What I would recommend doing is* >*clearing your browser’s cache and cookies, making all changes needed to* >*your metadata, and then attempt to upload the App Preview files again*

**---------- UPDATE - 23 september ----------**

I found a tricky solution. Not the best but it works... So my problem is each time I click on the SAVE button, my video preview disappears. EXCEPT if I upload the video previews at the all LAST step. So, everytime I want to release an update for my app, I have to do FIRST all the settings (add a build, change texts, pricing, languages, etc.) then I click on SAVE. After that step, when every settings has been set, I clear all the cache and cookies of Safari, I come back to iTunes Connect, I upload my video previews, then when they have been uploaded, I click on SUBMIT FOR REVIEW... Then it works...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem the other day.
But I was able to avoid it.

In my case:

- Primary Language is English.
- Additional Language is Japanese.
- Japanese screenshots use English screenshots.
- Only uploaded screenshots for iPhone 5.5 inch and iPad 12.9 inch. (Others use these screenshots)

In the above situation, the problem occurred. The App Preview disappeared after saving.

So, I decided to upload screenshots for each Language and it worked fine.
I guess the screenshots reference of the primary language is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clue. I will try this but my app has 5 languages and I want to show screenshots and video previews with the exact fit for the device... Don't want to check the box "Use screenshots of 5.5 inch etc.". So it's gonna be a long process if it's the only way to make it works...